# How to duplicate a case

Tags: civicase

We often have batches of six to eight related cases which have much of the same content (relationships, custom fields, activities). I would like to generate new cases by cloning an existing case multiple times. Before I embark on writing a new extension, has anyone already done something like this?

Comment: I dont really understand your question. You can create a case types which preloads a bunch of activities and roles (relationships). Is that waht you mean?

Comment: Thanks. Yes, we use case types extensively. These give you the structure for a new case, and a standardised set of activities, but it's essentially an empty case, ready for data entry. What I want to do is clone a case, complete with all the data (roles data, custom field contents, activities).

The obvious solution is an extension which creates a new empty case and then copies all the data from the source case to the new case, but I would need to hard-code the copying function for each different case type. I was hoping that there might be a better (ie more generic) way?

Comment: I would say have a look at the solution ErikH has mentioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another alternative might be to use the CiviRules extension, and develop your own action that prepopulates cases upon creation?

Check for https://civicrm.org/extensions/civirules the extension and https://docs.civicrm.org/civirules/en/latest/create-your-own-introduction/ for documentation on developing your own actions.